# How is NULL different from 0 in C?

Tags: c, null, zero

If these 3 lines are the only time NULL is mentioned in stdio.h, how is NULL different from 0 and most importantly what tells the compiler NULL is actually an invalid address? 
Talking about C, maybe in other libraries, like in iostream, NULL is defined differently.

```
0085 #ifndef NULL
0086 #define NULL 0
0087 #endif
```

Comment: What makes you think that the compiler does know that NULL is an invalid address?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html

Comment: @Yunnosch The way Clang compiles this function shows that it knows that `NULL` is an invalid address. https://godbolt.org/g/KsydcB

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm taught NULL and 0 are different, therefore the compiler must see some kind of difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the compiler, `NULL` is indistinguishable from `0` when used as a pointer. The standard actually defines `0` to be a null pointer value, and the standard library just introduces a convenient macro `NULL` defined to a null pointer value (usually `0` or `((void*)0)`), so that you can use it in code for better readability and expressing intent. But there's nothing special about `NULL` itself; it's the `0` that is relevant.

Comment: "To the compiler, NULL is indistinguishable from 0" if defined as `(void *)0` the size may differ. I got bitten by that on a 64-bit architecture when I passed 0 to nul terminate a variable length array.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added clarification; is it better?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, the classic `execl` problem? :-)

Comment: @melpomene someone just tried to edit the title as "Excel" instead of "execl" ...

Comment: @Angew yes. it was a cornercase but still...

Comment: *The standard actually defines 0 to be the null pointer value* The [standard defines `0` to be **a** null pointer value](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3), not **the** null pointer value.  "The null pointer value" does not have to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

To the compiler, all of `0`, `NULL` and `'\0'` map to the same value.  However, from the readability perspective, you may want to use the appropriate value depending on the context, to make it clear what you're trying to do and to improve the efficacy of code auditing and reviews.